# How do you append both pre-established text and user responses into a text area in Java?

Tags: java, textarea, append, textfield

I will do my best to explain-- I am trying to make a choose-your-own-adventure type game while using a TextField and a TextArea, where what is written in the TextField is appended into the TextArea (this I know how to do via ActionListener).

However, I need to have the TextArea start with a pre-written 'intro', which asks the user at the end if they want to continue or not. Therefore, I need it to be able to scan the user's response ('yes' or 'no') and choose the appropriate selection of pre-written text to follow.

I don't want to *overwrite* what is already in the TextArea, I want to add to it. I suppose what I'm confused about it how I'm supposed to lay out the entire file so that it functions properly, because the different choices for the adventure span different methods. Having 
"String text = textField.getText();" only within the actionPerformed method means I can't use 'text' elsewhere, but moving that line up with my other variables tells me it can't reference the field before it's defined.

I am fairly new to Java and am working on this as a project for a non-programming school course. I've been through many iterations thus far and this is what seems to be my final attempt, as I've remade it repeatedly and don't have much time left. :(

Comment: Right now I have the Strings 'input' and 'text' set up at the beginning of the class, the constructor is setting up the actual TextArea and TextField itself, the actionlistener is initializing 'input' (I think) and actually setting up the listener itself, and the method with all my actual text is doing absolutely nothing useful.

Edit: I should also note that in the text method, using textArea.append(text + "Hi, what's your name?") is not working. I can't seem to get the TextArea to start with any text it in whatsoever.

Comment: It looks like you're using the AWT graphics library for this project. If so, don't. Use Swing instead as it is much more robust and flexible. To append text to a JTextArea, with Swing all you need do is call the `append(String text)` method.

Comment: @Hovercraft -- Oops. I'm importing java.util.Scanner, java.awt.*, java.swing.*, and java.awt.event.*. Does that mean I'm using both? I thought I needed .awt for the event listener.

Comment: To use Swing components, you will use components whose name starts with a J, such as JTextArea, JTextField, and JButton. And yes you would use AWT event listeners and layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions/comments and my attempts to answer:

> I am trying to make a choose-your-own-adventure type game while using a TextField and a TextArea, where what is written in the TextField is appended into the TextArea (this I know how to do via ActionListener).

As per my comment, be sure to create a Swing GUI which would use a `JTextField` and a `JTextArea`. You would then add your `java.awt.event.ActionListener` to the `JTextArea`, and the ActionListener would respond whenever the user pressed `<ENTER>` within the `JTextField`.

> However, I need to have the TextArea start with a pre-written 'intro', which asks the user at the end if they want to continue or not. Therefore, I need it to be able to scan the user's response ('yes' or 'no') and choose the appropriate selection of pre-written text to follow.

This can be done easily, but sounds as if you may be trying to shoe-horn a linear console type program into a GUI. If so, consider reconsidering your program design since what works best for one often doesn't work well for another. If you do re-write, then you should consider redoing most including your program flow, but excepting perhaps the "model" portion of your previous program, the "business logic" that underlies everything.

> I don't want to overwrite what is already in the TextArea, I want to add to it. I suppose what I'm confused about it how I'm supposed to lay out the entire file so that it functions properly, because the different choices for the adventure span different methods. Having "String text = textField.getText();" only within the actionPerformed method means I can't use 'text' elsewhere, but moving that line up with my other variables tells me it can't reference the field before it's defined.

Again as per comments a JTextArea has an `append(String text)` method that will add new text to existing text that is already displayed in your JText Area. So on that note, your ActionListener's `actionPerformed` method could be very simple and look something like:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  String text = textField.getText();
  textArea.append(text):
}
```

Although you may need to add line feeds, `"\n"` either before and/or after the text you are going to append.